# Assertj+ How to create custom assertion for iterables

Tags: java, assertj

I need to create custom assertion for list items.

For example, I have ArrayList in which there is an Address Object, now I need to create a custom assertion to check anySatisfy

```
Assertions.assertThat(results.result).anySatisfy(p->{
        assertThat(p.getAddress().getCity()).withFailMessage("expected city: "+ "Caseros1").isEqualTo("Caseros1");
        assertThat(p.getAddress().getCountryName()).isEqualTo("Argentina");
    });
```

Any suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: and what error do you get when you do this?

Comment: I am looking to get individual error messages like "expected city not found" or "expected Country not found" but i get more generic error messages "Expecting any element of: <Result object> to satisfy the given assertions requirements but none did."

Answer (score 0):

This issue, which was since some time already available on `allSatisfy` is now also available in [release 3.12](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/milestone/42), see the respective [issue](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/1400).

So please upgrade to the latest AssertJ release and verify that this is working for you.